# OpenStack Hyper-V vSwitch not being selected

Tags: hyper-v, openstack, vswitch, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I'm updating this, as the original did not get much support. *And*, I'm not seeing that error anymore since restarting with a fresh install using [packstack.](https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/) To help try to *"help you, help me."* I am posting all the relevant configs for my install, in hopes that you can see a misconfiguration on my part. This was a fresh install of Rocky via [packstack.](https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/) on CentOS 7.6, and HyperVNovaCompute_Beta.msi from http://cloudbase.it. I had planned on just doing an initial base install with Hyper-V without OVS. After getting that running, setup a second Hyper-V server with OVS configured, using the same controller. I am having a hard time just getting the hyperv agent(non-OVS) to work properly and assign the "Servers" vSwitch to a new VM. I followed the same workflow that the [v-magine](https://github.com/cloudbase/v-magine) scripts use to do a install, looking through it's source to find out. (V-Magine would not install, I think there is new updates to [packstack.](https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/) and packages in repos that it gets stuck with.)

If there is anymore configs/settings that you need to see, just let me know.

Here is the setup
***Hyper01*** - HyperV

> **NIC1**(Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2): 172.16.1.91 with vSwitch "**Servers**" + Allow Management (No Extensions checked/enabled)

***OpenStack01*** - Controller VM on Hyper01

> **eth0**: 172.16.1.90, assigned to "**Servers**" vSwitch, VMQ enabled, MAC spoofing enabled # For management access
>   **eth1**(br-data): no ip, assigned to "**Servers**" vSwitch, VMQ enabled, MAC spoofing enabled # For future use with openvswitch, will move to new vSwitch when setup Open vSwitch
>   **eth2**(br-ext): no ip, assigned to "**Servers**" vSwitch, VMQ enabled, MAC spoofing enabled # For future use with openvswitch, will move to new vSwitch when setup Open vSwitch

#### Controller - openstack01(172.16.1.90):

**# ip address**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:01:5b:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.1.90/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:5b05/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:01:5b:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:5b08/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:01:5b:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:5b09/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:17:06:d6:d2:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-tun: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:81:ed:9b:a4:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: br-int: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ca:45:3c:bd:83:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: br-data: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:01:5b:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::f812:f0ff:fe21:6f43/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: br-ext: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:01:5b:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::483:e6ff:fe1a:aa4e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**# ovs-vsctl show**

```
d80df210-f9bc-4506-9674-18ebb803b301
    Manager "ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1"
        is_connected: true
    Bridge br-ext
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port phy-br-ext
            Interface phy-br-ext
                type: patch
                options: {peer=int-br-ext}
        Port "eth2"
            Interface "eth2"
        Port br-ext
            Interface br-ext
                type: internal
    Bridge br-data
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port "eth1"
            Interface "eth1"
        Port phy-br-data
            Interface phy-br-data
                type: patch
                options: {peer=int-br-data}
        Port br-data
            Interface br-data
                type: internal
    Bridge br-tun
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port patch-int
            Interface patch-int
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-tun}
        Port br-tun
            Interface br-tun
                type: internal
    Bridge br-int
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port int-br-data
            Interface int-br-data
                type: patch
                options: {peer=phy-br-data}
        Port patch-tun
            Interface patch-tun
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-int}
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port int-br-ext
            Interface int-br-ext
                type: patch
                options: {peer=phy-br-ext}
        Port "qr-fd8d84fe-71"
            tag: 1
            Interface "qr-fd8d84fe-71"
                type: internal
        Port "tapd2b841f2-41"
            tag: 1
            Interface "tapd2b841f2-41"
                type: internal
        Port "qg-75a54182-7e"
            tag: 2
            Interface "qg-75a54182-7e"
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.10.1"
```

**/etc/nova/nova.conf**

```
[DEFAULT]
debug=False
instance_usage_audit_period=hour
rootwrap_config=/etc/nova/rootwrap.conf
compute_driver=libvirt.LibvirtDriver
allow_resize_to_same_host=True
vif_plugging_is_fatal=True
vif_plugging_timeout=300
force_raw_images=True
reserved_host_memory_mb=512
cpu_allocation_ratio=16.0
ram_allocation_ratio=1.5
instance_usage_audit=True
heal_instance_info_cache_interval=60
force_snat_range=0.0.0.0/0
metadata_host=172.16.1.90
dhcp_domain=novalocal
firewall_driver=nova.virt.firewall.NoopFirewallDriver
ssl_only=False
state_path=/var/lib/nova
report_interval=10
service_down_time=60
enabled_apis=osapi_compute,metadata
osapi_compute_listen=0.0.0.0
osapi_compute_listen_port=8774
osapi_compute_workers=2
metadata_listen=0.0.0.0
metadata_listen_port=8775
metadata_workers=2
log_dir=/var/log/nova
transport_url=rabbit://openstack:***@172.16.1.90:5672/
volume_api_class=nova.volume.cinder.API

[api]
auth_strategy=keystone
use_forwarded_for=False
fping_path=/usr/sbin/fping

[api_database]
connection=mysql+pymysql://nova_api:***@172.16.1.90/nova_api

[conductor]
workers=2

[database]
connection=mysql+pymysql://nova:***@172.16.1.90/nova

[filter_scheduler]
host_subset_size=1
max_io_ops_per_host=8
max_instances_per_host=50
available_filters=nova.scheduler.filters.all_filters
enabled_filters=RetryFilter,AvailabilityZoneFilter,RamFilter,DiskFilter,ComputeFilter,ComputeCapabilitiesFilter,ImagePropertiesFilter,ServerGroupAntiAffinityFilter,ServerGroupAffinityFilter,CoreFilter
weight_classes=nova.scheduler.weights.all_weighers

[glance]
api_servers=http://172.16.1.90:9292

[key_manager]
backend=nova.keymgr.conf_key_mgr.ConfKeyManager

[keystone_authtoken]
www_authenticate_uri=http://172.16.1.90:5000/
auth_uri=http://172.16.1.90:5000/
auth_type=password
auth_url=http://172.16.1.90:5000/v3
username=nova
password=***
user_domain_name=Default
project_name=services
project_domain_name=Default

[libvirt]
virt_type=qemu
inject_password=False
inject_key=False
inject_partition=-2
live_migration_uri=qemu+tcp://%s/system
cpu_mode=none
vif_driver=nova.virt.libvirt.vif.LibvirtGenericVIFDriver

[neutron]
url=http://172.16.1.90:9696
ovs_bridge=br-int
default_floating_pool=public
extension_sync_interval=600
service_metadata_proxy=True
metadata_proxy_shared_secret=***
timeout=60
auth_type=v3password
auth_url=http://172.16.1.90:5000/v3
project_name=services
project_domain_name=Default
username=neutron
user_domain_name=Default
password=***
region_name=SouthCentral

[notifications]
notify_on_state_change=vm_and_task_state

[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path=/var/lib/nova/tmp

[oslo_messaging_notifications]
driver=messagingv2

[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
ssl=False

[oslo_policy]
policy_file=/etc/nova/policy.json

[placement]
auth_type=password
auth_url=http://172.16.1.90:5000/v3
project_name=services
project_domain_name=Default
username=placement
user_domain_name=Default
password=***
region_name=SouthCentral

[placement_database]
connection=mysql+pymysql://nova_placement:***@172.16.1.90/nova_placement

[scheduler]
driver=filter_scheduler
max_attempts=3
workers=2

[spice]
enabled=False

[vendordata_dynamic_auth]
project_domain_name=Default
user_domain_name=Default

[vnc]
enabled=True
keymap=en-us
novncproxy_base_url=http://172.16.1.90:6080/vnc_auto.html
novncproxy_host=0.0.0.0
novncproxy_port=6080
auth_schemes=none
vncserver_proxyclient_address=openstack01
vncserver_listen=0.0.0.0

[wsgi]
api_paste_config=api-paste.ini
```

**/etc/neutron/neutron.conf**

```
[DEFAULT]
debug=False
bind_host=0.0.0.0
auth_strategy=keystone
core_plugin=neutron.plugins.ml2.plugin.Ml2Plugin
service_plugins=qos,trunk,router,metering
allow_overlapping_ips=True
notify_nova_on_port_status_changes=True
notify_nova_on_port_data_changes=True
api_workers=2
rpc_workers=2
router_scheduler_driver=neutron.scheduler.l3_agent_scheduler.ChanceScheduler
l3_ha=False
max_l3_agents_per_router=3
log_dir=/var/log/neutron
transport_url=rabbit://***:***@172.16.1.90:5672/
control_exchange=neutron

[agent]
root_helper=sudo neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf

[database]
connection=mysql+pymysql://neutron:***@172.16.1.90/neutron

[keystone_authtoken]
www_authenticate_uri=http://172.16.1.90:5000/
auth_uri=http://172.16.1.90:5000/
auth_type=password
auth_url=http://172.16.1.90:5000/v3
username=neutron
password=***
user_domain_name=Default
project_name=services
project_domain_name=Default

[nova]
region_name=SouthCentral
auth_url=http://172.16.1.90:5000/v3
auth_type=password
password=***
project_domain_id=default
project_domain_name=Default
project_name=services
tenant_name=services
user_domain_id=default
user_domain_name=Default
username=nova

[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path=$state_path/lock

[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
ssl=False

[oslo_policy]
policy_file=/etc/neutron/policy.json
```

**/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini**

```
[DEFAULT]
debug=False

[ml2]
type_drivers=vxlan,flat
tenant_network_types=vxlan
mechanism_drivers=openvswitch,hyperv
extension_drivers=port_security,qos
path_mtu=0

[ml2_type_flat]
flat_networks=*

[ml2_type_vxlan]
vni_ranges=10:100
vxlan_group=224.0.0.1

[securitygroup]
firewall_driver=neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.OVSHybridIptablesFirewallDriver
enable_security_group=True
```

**/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/openvswitch_agent.ini**

```
[DEFAULT]
debug=False

[agent]
tunnel_types=vxlan
vxlan_udp_port=4789
l2_population=False
drop_flows_on_start=False

[ovs]
integration_bridge=br-int
tunnel_bridge=br-tun
local_ip=172.16.1.90
bridge_mappings=physnet1:br-data,extnet:br-ext

[securitygroup]
firewall_driver=neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.OVSHybridIptablesFirewallDriver
```

#### Compute - Hyper01(172.16.1.91):

**PS> Get-NetAdapter**

```
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
vEthernet (Servers)       Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter              2 Up           00-10-18-14-2C-3A         1 Gbps
Ethernet                  Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2        3 Up           00-10-18-14-2C-3A         1 Gbps
Storage SAN               QLogic Dual Port 10 Gigabit Ethernet...       5 Up           00-0E-1E-04-D0-14        10 Gbps
Unused SAN                QLogic Dual Port 10 Gigabit Ethern...#2       7 Disconnected 00-0E-1E-04-D0-10          0 bps
```

**Compute install command used** (HyperVNovaCompute_Beta.msi downloaded on 1/14/2019 11:03 PM)

```
msiexec /I HyperVNovaCompute_Beta.msi /l*v nova_install.log ADDLOCAL=HyperVNovaCompute,NeutronHyperVAgent,iSCSISWInitiator,FreeRDP PLACEMENTAUTHURL="http://172.16.1.90:5000/v3" PLACEMENTPASSWORD=*** PLACEMENTPROJECTNAME=services PLACEMENTUSERNAME=placement PLACEMENTDOMAINNAME=Default PLACEMENTUSERDOMAINNAME=Default RPCTRANSPORTURL="rabbit://openstack:***@172.16.1.90:5672/" GLANCEURL="http://172.16.1.90:9292" INSTANCESPATH="\\STORAGE\VMs\" LOGDIR="C:\OpenStack\Log\" RDPCONSOLEURL="http://Hyper01:8000" ADDVSWITCH=0 VSWITCHNAME="Servers" USECOWIMAGES=0 FORCECONFIGDRIVE=1 CONFIGDRIVEINJECTPASSWORD=1 DYNAMICMEMORYRATIO=1 ENABLELOGGING=1 VERBOSELOGGING=1 NEUTRONURL="http://172.16.1.90:9696" NEUTRONADMINTENANTNAME=services NEUTRONADMINUSERNAME=neutron NEUTRONADMINPASSWORD=*** NEUTRONADMINAUTHURL="http://172.16.1.90:5000/v3" NEUTRONDOMAINNAME=Default NEUTRONUSERDOMAINNAME=Default NOVACOMPUTESERVICEUSER="svc-nova-compute" NOVACOMPUTESERVICEPASSWORD=***
```

**C:\Program Files\Cloudbase Solutions\OpenStack\Nova\etc\nova.conf**

```
[DEFAULT]
debug=False
compute_driver=compute_hyperv.driver.HyperVDriver
instances_path=\\STORAGE\VMs\
use_cow_images=false
force_config_drive=true
flat_injected=true
mkisofs_cmd=C:\Program Files\Cloudbase Solutions\OpenStack\Nova\bin\mkisofs.exe
allow_resize_to_same_host=true
running_deleted_instance_poll_interval=120
resize_confirm_window=5
resume_guests_state_on_host_boot=true
transport_url=rabbit://openstack:***@172.16.1.90:5672/
rpc_response_timeout=1800
lock_path=C:\OpenStack\Log\
vif_plugging_is_fatal=false
vif_plugging_timeout=60
block_device_allocate_retries=600
log_dir=C:\OpenStack\Log\
log_file=nova-compute.log
instance_usage_audit=true
instance_usage_audit_period=hour

[placement]
auth_strategy=keystone
auth_type=password
auth_url=http://172.16.1.90:5000/v3
project_name=services
username=placement
password=***
project_domain_name=Default
user_domain_name=Default
os_region_name=SouthCentral

[notifications]
notify_on_state_change=vm_and_task_state

[glance]
api_servers=http://172.16.1.90:9292

[hyperv]
limit_cpu_features=false
config_drive_inject_password=true
qemu_img_cmd=C:\Program Files\Cloudbase Solutions\OpenStack\Nova\bin\qemu-img.exe
config_drive_cdrom=true
dynamic_memory_ratio=1
enable_instance_metrics_collection=true

[os_win]
cache_temporary_wmi_objects=false

[rdp]
enabled=true
html5_proxy_base_url=http://Hyper01:8000

[neutron]
url=http://172.16.1.90:9696
auth_strategy=keystone
project_name=services
username=neutron
password=
auth_url=http://172.16.1.90:5000/v3
project_domain_name=Default
user_domain_name=Default
os_region_name=SouthCentral
auth_type=password
service_metadata_proxy = true
metadata_proxy_shared_secret = ***
```

**C:\Program Files\Cloudbase Solutions\OpenStack\Nova\etc\neutron_hyperv_agent.conf**

```
[DEFAULT]
control_exchange=neutron
transport_url=rabbit://openstack:***@172.16.1.90:5672
log_dir=C:\OpenStack\Log\
log_file=neutron-hyperv-agent.log

[AGENT]
polling_interval=2
physical_network_vswitch_mappings=*:Servers
enable_metrics_collection=true
enable_qos_extension=false

[SECURITYGROUP]
firewall_driver=hyperv
enable_security_group=true
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the network adapter from the guest and installing a legacy network adapter?

Comment: What guest?? Are you familiar with OpenStack? Also, legacy network adapter hasn't been in hyper-v for some time now.

Comment: https://cloudbase.it/neutron-hyper-v-plugin/  sure you've gone through it but double check ip forwarding and install the hyperv python package.  configs look fine.  have errors or stopped services to show?

Comment: Thanks, time was of the essence, so I scrapped it and started over deploying it with OVS instead of the HyperV agent. When I have time within the next few weeks, I will setup another Hyper-V server and attempt to get it working without OVS and just the HyperV agent. So I now have two test VMs deployed on their private network of 10.0.0.0/24. They both can ping each other, but not the OVS router that's @ 10.0.0.1. Any suggestions on what to look at?

Comment: I'm not seeing any ports being listen to on the controller or compute when I run `ovs-appctl tnl/ports/show`